# Выгрузить список магазинов Магнит

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Нужно выгрузить адреса магазинов и координаты с сайта магнита. На сколько я понял у них отсутствует какой либо api.
При запросе к сайту

```
import requests
import json


r = requests.get('https://magnit.ru/shops/')
print(r.text)
```

в `var elementsArr` вроде как присутствует некие координаты и адреса.

```
var elementsArr = 
{"points" :
  [
      {
       "id": 49215,
       "city": "2398",
       "lat": "55.742145",
       "lng": "37.520419",
       "address": "\u0433. \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430,\u0443\u043b. 1812 \u0433\u043e\u0434\u0430,12.
      }
  ]
}
```

Как мне вытащить `lat` , `lng` и `address`

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример выдачи, что у вас не получается распарсить

Comment: Через BeautifulSoup придётся парсить

Comment: @CrazyElf а если интересующие меня данные находятся в <div><script> как в ``soup.find_all`` это прописать

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Действия:

- Регуляркой вытащить `var elementsArr = ...;`
- Распарсить как json
- Работать с данными из `elementsArr`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ccd16c3e5fb7cd00e4f585905074fc717cc47ba6/html_parsing/magnit_ru__shops.py#L22)

```
import json
import re

import requests

rs = requests.get('https://magnit.ru/shops/')
m = re.search('var elementsArr = (.+);', rs.text)

data = json.loads(m.group(1))
points = data['points']

print(f'Points ({len(points)}):')
for p in points:
    print(f"  lat: {p['lat']}, lng: {p['lng']}")

# Points (617):
#   lat: 55.742145, lng: 37.520419
#   lat: 55.741764, lng: 37.520348
#   lat: 55.741757, lng: 37.520355
#   ...
#   lat: 55.877706, lng: 37.731395
#   lat: 55.876482, lng: 37.721799
#   lat: 55.878682, lng: 37.719253
```

---

**PS.**

По хорошему, перед использованием `m.group(1)` лучше проверить `m`, т.к. если регулярка не сможет найти, то в `m` будет `None`, пример так:

```
if not m:
    print(f'[-] Не удалось регуляркой найти "var elementsArr"')
    # И в зависимости от места вызова:
    # return      # Выходим из функции
    # sys.exit()  # или завершаем работу скрипта

data = json.loads(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из:

> в `var elementsArr` вроде как присутствует некие координаты и адреса.

```
elementsArr = {"points" :
  [
      {
       "id": 49215,
       "city": "2398",
       "lat": "55.742145",
       "lng": "37.520419",
       "address": "\u0433. \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430,\u0443\u043b. 1812 \u0433\u043e\u0434\u0430,12."
      }
  ]
}

print(elementsArr['points'][0]['lat'])
print(elementsArr['points'][0]['lng'])
print(elementsArr['points'][0]['address'])
```

а вообще `r = requests.get('https://magnit.ru/shops/')` вернёт HTML страницы